# Log out from chat doesnt work

Tags: bug, logout

I was trying to logout from stackoverflow and i tried it by clicking on logout link at from https://chat.stackoverflow.com/ and it done nothing i am still logged in

Comment: Reproduced on Chrome 44 on windows 10. This appears to be broken.

Comment: Same here Chrome 44 windows 7.

Comment: I guess clearing your cache & cookies should "solve" the issue ;-)

Comment: Reproduced on Firefox 40.0.2 on Windows 7

Comment: Why are you logging out of chat anyway? :(

Comment: @poke i want my life back :(

Comment: Please use Firefox. It works there.

Comment: Reproduced on Firefox 38.0.1 on Macos

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315174/logout-of-chat-stackoverflow-com-is-not-working/315189#315189