# "Logout" of chat.stackoverflow.com is not working?

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, logout

Steps to re-produce this bug -

1. Login to SO, navigate to chat
2. Click on upper left Arrow Logout link
3. System asks for confirmation - "Are you sure you want to logout?"
4. After confirming the decision, page refreshes and again comes back on chat home page

Is this expected behavior ? If not, how to logout from Chat site WITHOUT going back to Main site ?

Thanks!

Comment: Which upper left arrow are you referring to? I don't see any while in a chat room.

Comment: Not in chat room. Please check the added image in my question.

Comment: 1+ I was able to reproduce this.

Comment: Confirmed; looking into it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed; thanks. The "{chat}/logout" link shown pre-dated a few of our auth / universal-login changes, and was doomed to never work (we just identified you again and issued you with fresh chat cookies right away). We now link to the correct universal logout.